# PYSPARK : Finding a Mean of a variables excluding the top 1 percentile of data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science

I have a dataset which is getting grouped by multiple variables where we finding aggregates like mean , std dev etc. Now i want to find Mean of a variables excluding the top 1 percentile of data

I am trying something like

```
         df_final=df.groupby(groupbyElement).agg(mean('value').alias('Mean'),stddev('value').alias('Stddev'),expr('percentile(value, array(0.99))')[0].alias('99_percentile'),mean(when(col('value')<=col('99_percentile'),col('value')))
```

But it seems spark cannot use the agg name which is defined in the same group statement.

I even tried this ,

~df_final=df.groupby(groupbyElement).agg(mean('value').alias('Mean'),stddev('value').alias('Stddev'),mean(when(col('value')<=expr('percentile(value, array(0.99))')[0],col('value')))~

But it throws below error:
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.

I hope some one would be able to answer this

Update :
I try doing the otherway

Comment: not sure this is going to be possible in one pass. your '99_percentile' isn't created when you're trying to filter on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward modification of your code. It will aggregate df twice. As far as I can tell, that's what is required.

```
df_final=(
          df.join(df
                  .groupby(groupbyElement)
                  .agg(expr('percentile(value, array(0.99))')[0].alias('99_percentile'), 
                        on=["groupbyElement"], how="left"
                  )
          .groupby(groupbyElement)
          .agg(mean('value').alias('Mean'), 
               stddev('value').alias('Stddev'),
               mean(when(col('value')<=col('99_percentile'), col('value')))
          )
```